# Python datetime to Unix epoch timestamp

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert pandas datetime object to unix/epoch timestamp. I am getting an error for one particular date in the dataset.

The timestamps I am trying are these:

1) 2019-08-31 21:38:00

2) 2019-01-09 16:26:00

I am using Python's datetime module:

```py
1) datetime.strptime('2019-08-31 21:38:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp()
1567280280.0

2) datetime.strptime('2019-01-09 16:26:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp()
1547047560.0
```

Although Object (2) is greater than (1), the epoch timestamps in python shows otherwise.

When I convert the same datetime objects to numerical values in excel, I get:

1) '2019-08-31 21:38:00' -> 43708.901389

2) '2019-01-09 16:26:00' -> 43709.684722

Which is correct. Object (2) > Object (1).

Clearly Date (1) is smaller than Date (2).

Why is it showing the wrong order using python?

Comment: `2019-01-09 16:26:00` is Jan 09? Why should it be larger than `2019-08-31 21:38:00`, which is Aug 31?

Comment: Date 1 is September 2019, Date 2 is January. Everything works as intended here